# Java: How to create a Tableoutput

Tags: java, string, format, output

does anyone know an easy way to make a table-output? I have to make some runtimetests and show them in a table (at the console).

Something like this:

|=====================================|
|-------ArrayList-------------|---------LinkedList----------|
|add_|remove_|contains_|  add_|remove_|contains|
|time_|time___|time____| time_|time___|time____|
|time_|time___|time____| time_|time___|time____|
|time_|time___|time____| time_|time___|time____|

its not that shiny, but maybe you get a feeling of what I need.
I would appreciate any answer!

Moritz

Comment: Loop around both the list in a single for loop and use `\t` to arrange things in a presentable way.

Comment: thx for your answer. This works fine, but i search for a way to present it with borders and if possible with the option of adding another row. (ive got an array of classes to test)
Or is it utopian?